# Did you miss me? Here's a riddle!

Tags: riddle, pattern

*My first is sunny and may be found here in Hades;

My second is funny and may be found here in Hell.*

*My third is charged, found liberated in Alicante;

My fourth is rare and found liberated in Iberia.*

*My sixth is hard and found secretly in knickers;

My seventh is fertile and found often in pants.*

**What is my fifth?**

(I'll add more tags if this one seems hard or too broad.)

Comment: @Emrakul I didn't want to use the <pre> tag, but some of the text kept disappearing when I just used ordinary text! Let me know if you find a better workaround :-)

Comment: It's actually [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/206222).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Your fifth is black, and can be found buried in fiberglass*

You are the

> Periodic table of elements

The clues each have a property of a member, along with a couple words containing the "name":

> **Hydrogen:**
>  sunny (it's found in the sun)
>  **H** is in *here* and *Hades*
>
>  **Helium:**
>  funny (you talk funny when inhaled)
>  **He** in *here* and *Hell*
>
>  **Lithium:**
>  charged (commonly used in batteries)
>  **Li** in *liberated* and *Alicante*
>
>  **Beryllium:**
>  rare (it's just rare, and not found alone)
>  **Be** in *liberated* and *Iberia*
>
>  **Carbon:**
>  hard (think diamonds)
>  **C** in *secretly* and *knickers*
>
>  **Nitrogen:**
>  fertile (most fertilizers contain it)
>  **N** in *often* and *pants*

So that makes the fifth one:

> **Boron**:
>  black (one of it's "natural" appearances)
>  **B** in *buried* and *fiberglass*

Thanks to GentlePurpleRain in comments for the last set of clues.

Comment: Jeez, that was quick! And there was me thinking it might've been too hard...

Comment: I got it from the first two, for the record. Had to look up a list for the rest.

Comment: I'm sitting here looking at the last line, with 'egg' for fertile and 'leg' for found in pants, trying to figure out the rest of the "add a letter to the front" pairs...I think you're probably more correct than me...

Comment: I had Elysium for Hades because it's the nicest part..

Comment: Could you explain how the 'sunny', 'funny', etc. clues work? Also there's a sequence of clues you haven't picked up on yet...

Comment: Hmm, I can add in the descriptions. Not sure about the extra clue. I'm sure it has to do with liberated/secretly/here/often, but not sure how.

Comment: funny is when you breathe in helium and talk funny

Comment: sunny because the sun is made of 70% hydrogen gas?

Comment: You're right that it's to do with liberated/secretly/here/often. I won't say any more at this stage.

Comment: Hmm, can you answer if the fifth would be found "often" in my example?

Comment: @Geobits, I think the fifth would be found *habitually* in fiberglass.  (The descriptive words also contain the element's abbreviation:  ***h***ere, ***he***re, ***li***berated, li***be***rated, (ha***b***itually), se***c***retly, ofte***n***)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Makes sense. I was thinking something about the position of the abbreviations (here means first letter, liberated second, often third, etc). Still feels like something's missing, though.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain has got it!

Comment: You did put **the spoiler tag** on the explanation, but not on the solution itself…

Comment: @Lohoris I don't understand. If you mean the "*Your fifth is black...*" line, I don't consider that the solution. The last spoilered block is the solution. The first line is just another clue to it IMO, in the style of the OP..